# Tracking different domains within 1 view and using filters in GA - is it possible?

Tags: google-analytics

Was curious if the following was possible. We have a site, https://mysite.net

Say we want to track https://dev.mysite.net but keep it in the same view. The problem is we have around 80+ instances of different subdomains that they want tracked and the limit is 50. This works when creating different views for each, but I am trying to use filters for each subdomain and it doesn't seem to work.

So at the moment I have one view set to 
    https://mysite.net. 
    And 3 filters set to
    https://site1.mysite.net
    https://site2.mysite.net
    https://site3.mysite.net

All are set to "include only"  "traffic to the hostname"   "that contain" 
with the their respective URL.

Will this work does anyone know ? Or do you need different views for sure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a custom filter type > include with the filter field hostname, and a regex of `^site[1-3]\.mysite\.net$`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! is this in addition to the 3 filters I created already?

Comment: Should only need that one filter

Comment: Ok - I'll have to test this with one of the views, so if there are 4 different sites it'll be site[1-4] I'd imagine. Each view has their own instance, it's just the subdomains that are a problem

Comment: Thanks, but nothing is showing up in real time. I have it configured like so. In property settings for the view is product.mysite.net. I created a filter with what you suggested but there's nothing showing

Comment: I'm shooting in the dark, but try instead of using mysite.net, rather than product.mysite.net

Comment: no luck :(  just to clarify. I have property setting of view at mysite.net, then filters such as product.mysite.net (include only hostname that containt) I am thinking I have to specify each domain since each one will have different instances that the custom filter might not pick up specifically. I'm starting to dislike GA :)

Comment: Scope out this blog post on [How To Use More Than One Include Filter (without losing data)](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2011/06/24/more-than-one-include-filter/#sr=g&m=o&cp=or&ct=-tmc&st=(opu%20qspwjefe)&ts=1404834823). Might give you some ideas on how you can get it to work.